# My connection string is not working for signalR

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012

My Entities has name crowdfundingEnities4 and userdataEntities6.But i want crowddfundingEntities4 to use for notification.

I have created a new sqlConnectionString with name sqlConString.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-saroh-20170305155508;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-saroh-20170305155508.mdf" />
    <add name="crowdfundingEntities4" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Model1.csdl|res://*/Models.Model1.ssdl|res://*/Models.Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\crowdfunding.mdf;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <add name="userdataEntities6" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.MyModel.csdl|res://*/Models.MyModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.MyModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\userdata.mdf;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <add name="sqlConString" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\crowdfunding.mdf;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework';" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

**My code in Global.aspx is as follow**

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        string con = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["crowdfundingEntities4"].ConnectionString;
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
            SqlDependency.Start(con);
        }
```

But it is showing different error on line `SqlDepedency.Start(con)`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your database server is configured, the service broker is enable and your user has all the permission required? 
In order to use SqlDependency it requires Service Broker.  So you have to enable Service Broker on the database and check the minimum database permission required

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12862/Minimum-Database-Permissions-Required-for-SqlDepen